# Incorrect order of matplotlib bars

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a barchart, where the y axis is the list of months from Jan to Dec and the x axis values are stored in another list in corresponding order.
When I plot the graph, the order of months gets mixed up.

```
In:  

fig, ((ax1, ax2)) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(10,5), sharex='row')

fig.suptitle("Income from members and supporters", fontsize=14)

ax1.barh(months, tag_max)
ax1.set_facecolor('white')
ax1.set_title("Maximum income from members")

ax2.barh(months, tam_max)
ax2.set_facecolor('white')
ax2.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
ax2.set_title('Maximum income from supporters')
```

Out:

[image]

```
In:

    months

Out:

    ['January',
     'February',
     'March',
     'April',
     'May',
     'June',
     'July',
     'August',
     'September',
     'October',
     'November',
     'December']
```

What can be the reason and how can i fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: The reason is that your y axis are strings. Matplotlib then automatically sorts these alphabetically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment by DavidG is correct. You can get around the problem by using numerical values for your bar position and 
assigning the months as `yticklabels`

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

months = [
    'January',
    'February',
    'March',
    'April',
    'May',
    'June',
    'July',
    'August',
    'September',
    'October',
    'November',
    'December'
]

tag_max = np.random.rand(len(months))
tam_max = np.random.rand(len(months))

yticks = [i for i in range(len(months))]

fig, ((ax1, ax2)) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(10,5), sharex='row')

fig.suptitle("Income from members and supporters", fontsize=14)

ax1.barh(yticks, tag_max)
ax1.set_facecolor('white')
ax1.set_title("Maximum income from members")
ax1.set_yticks(yticks)
ax1.set_yticklabels(months)


ax2.barh(yticks, tam_max)
ax2.set_facecolor('white')
ax2.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
ax2.set_title('Maximum income from supporters')

plt.show()
```

This gives the following output:

[image: result of the given code]

Comment: Hah I didn't think of that, thank you very much!